# I got my Census badge on the wrong site

Tags: bug, badges, survey-2020

today I was visiting the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site when I got notified about the survey. I clicked the link, immediately. I filled out the form, but it returned me back to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, thus I got the tag in this site, instead of StackOverflow.

This survey was about Programming from StackOverflow, thus I should get my badge on this page, not on any other site.

[image]

[image]

It's missing on [my badge page at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540350/martin-braun?tab=badges) but [shown on my Unix.SE profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/279653/martin-braun?tab=badges)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the survey, you are presented with a screen similar to the one below.  You can either accept the badge on the site you were on when you clicked the banner, or click "View other eligible sites" which reveals options to redeem from various sites, including SO.

Once you accept the badge (on any site) it cannot be transferred.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems I clicked by accident, I cannot change this anymore? Well then, I thought it was a bug.